# Setup a docker development environment for php without getting '403 access denied error'

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile

I develop a php application and I want to be able to run my application as `www-data` without getting http error 403.

I have the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:5.6-fpm-alpine
MAINTAINER Dimitrios Desyllas <pcmagas@disroot.org>

ARG XDEBUG_HOST="172.17.0.1"
ARG XDEBUG_PORT="9021"

RUN apk add --update --virtual build_deps gcc g++ autoconf make &&\
    apk add --update postgresql-dev libmcrypt-dev libxml2-dev &&\
    docker-php-source extract &&\
    docker-php-ext-install pdo mysqli pdo_mysql pgsql pdo_pgsql mbstring mcrypt xmlreader &&\
    pecl install xdebug-2.5.5 &&\
    docker-php-ext-enable xdebugpdo mysqli pdo_mysql pgsql pdo_pgsql mbstring mcrypt xmlreader &&\
    echo "xdebug.remote_enable=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini &&\
    echo "xdebug.remote_autostart=0" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini &&\
    echo "xdebug.remote_connect_back=0" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini &&\
    echo "xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini &&\
    echo "xdebug.remote_mode = req" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini &&\
    echo "xdebug.remote_log=/var/log/xdebug/xdebug_remote.log" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini &&\
    echo "xdebug.remote_host=${XDEBUG_HOST}" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini &&\
    echo "xdebug.remote_port=${XDEBUG_PORT}" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini &&\
    mkdir -p /var/log/xdebug &&\
    touch  /var/log/xdebug/xdebug_remote.log &&\
    chmod 766 /var/log/xdebug/xdebug_remote.log &&\
    docker-php-source delete &&\
    apk del build_deps &&\
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* &&\
    rm -rf /tmp/*


ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-l", "-c", "php-fpm"]
```

I use it in order to have a unified development environment for my php applications without the need to install a LEMP or a LAMP stack. (In a similar way that vagrant works)

I launch it using the following `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2'
services:

 phpBB_dev:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
    args:
      #Over GNU/Linux run ifconfig and look for docker0 interface
      XDEBUG_HOST: 172.17.0.1
      # If phpstorm or your IDE listens to anoither port please change it
      XDEBUG_PORT: 9021
  image: 'pcmagas/phpbb_dev'
  links:
    - mariadb
    - postgresql
  volumes:
    - "$SRC_PATH:/var/www/html:Z"

 nginx:
  image: nginx:alpine
  ports:
    - "5092:5092"
  links:
    - "phpBB_dev"
  volumes:
    - './nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro'
    - './logs/dev/nginx:/var/logs'
  volumes_from:
    - 'phpBB_dev'

 mariadb:
  image: mariadb
  environment:
    MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: "yes"
    MYSQL_ONETIME_PASSWORD: "yes"
    MYSQL_DATABASE: 'phpBB'
    MYSQL_USER: 'phpbb'
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'phpp_unsafe_passwd'

 postgresql:
  image: postgres
  environment:
    POSTGRES_DB: 'phpbb'
    POSTGRES_USER: 'phpbb'
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'phpp_unsafe_passwd'
```

And I mount my project's path into `$SRC_PATH` enviromental variable via `.env` file. As mentioned above I get error 403 with the following setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should modify the `Dockerfile` like that:

```
FROM php:5.6-fpm-alpine
MAINTAINER Dimitrios Desyllas <pcmagas@disroot.org>

ARG XDEBUG_HOST="172.17.0.1"
ARG XDEBUG_PORT="9021"
ARG UID='1000'
ARG GID='1000'

COPY ./entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
COPY ./fpm.conf /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/zz-docker.conf

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh &&\
    apk add --update --virtual build_deps gcc g++ autoconf make &&\
    apk add --update postgresql-dev libmcrypt-dev libxml2-dev &&\
    docker-php-source extract &&\
    docker-php-ext-install pdo mysqli pdo_mysql pgsql pdo_pgsql mbstring mcrypt xmlreader &&\
    pecl install xdebug-2.5.5 &&\
    docker-php-ext-enable xdebug pdo mysqli pdo_mysql pgsql pdo_pgsql mbstring mcrypt xmlreader &&\
    echo "xdebug.remote_enable=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini &&\
    echo "xdebug.remote_autostart=0" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini &&\
    echo "xdebug.remote_connect_back=0" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini &&\
    echo "xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini &&\
    echo "xdebug.remote_mode = req" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini &&\
    echo "xdebug.remote_log=/var/log/xdebug/xdebug_remote.log" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini &&\
    echo "xdebug.remote_host=${XDEBUG_HOST}" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini &&\
    echo "xdebug.remote_port=${XDEBUG_PORT}" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini &&\
    mkdir -p /var/log/xdebug &&\
    touch  /var/log/xdebug/xdebug_remote.log &&\
    chmod 766 /var/log/xdebug/xdebug_remote.log &&\
    docker-php-source delete &&\
    apk del build_deps &&\
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* &&\
    rm -rf /tmp/* &&\
    adduser -D -H -S -s /bin/false -G www-data -u ${UID} developer

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

As you can see I did the following changes to your `Dockerfile`:

- Added a user having your system's user id and group id therefore won't have any permission related problem and you can modify the files as you please
- I inserted an `entrypoint.sh` script because any *.php file should have the executable linux permission where it can be done by following entrypoint:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh

  find /var/www/html -iname "*.php" | xargs chmod +x

  exec "$@"
  ```

I also in order to work is recomended the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:

 phpBB_dev:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
    args:
      #Over GNU/Linux run ifconfig and look for docker0 interface
      XDEBUG_HOST: 172.17.0.1
      # If phpstorm or your IDE listens to anoither port please change it
      XDEBUG_PORT: 9021
      # IN order to change theese parameters run whoami in your terminal
      UID: 1000
      GID: 1000
  image: 'pcmagas/phpbb_dev'
  links:
    - mariadb
    - postgresql
  volumes:
    - "$SRC_PATH:/var/www/html:Z"

 nginx:
  image: nginx:alpine
  ports:
    - "5092:5092"
  links:
    - "phpBB_dev"
  volumes:
    - './nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro'
    - './logs/dev/nginx:/var/logs'
  volumes_from:
    - 'phpBB_dev'

 mariadb:
  image: mariadb
  environment:
    MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: "yes"
    MYSQL_ONETIME_PASSWORD: "yes"
    MYSQL_DATABASE: 'phpBB'
    MYSQL_USER: 'phpbb'
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'phpp_unsafe_passwd'

 postgresql:
  image: postgres
  environment:
    POSTGRES_DB: 'phpbb'
    POSTGRES_USER: 'phpbb'
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'phpp_unsafe_passwd'
```

As you can see the `UID` && `GID` must have the current user's group id and user id. The linux/unix command `whoami` should give this info. Also In order to work you should create the following file named `fpm.conf`

```
[global]
daemonize = no

[www]
listen = 9000
user = developer
group = www-data
```

In other words I extended the default `zz-docker.conf` file used from `php:5.6-fpm-alpine` in order to use a custom user and a custom group with the very same user id and group id as the host's one user that uses in order to develop without any 'mysterious' user and owner changes.

Even untested for php-7.* versions I guess it should work like a charm.